# Can anyone help me to optimize my query?

Tags: sql-server-2008

```
 SELECT p.ID, Name
   FROM Policies p
        INNER JOIN ProgramYears py ON p.ProgramYearID = py.id
        INNER JOIN (SELECT MemberID, max(EffectiveDate) AS EffectiveDate
                      FROM Policies
                     GROUP BY MemberID) TEMP
                ON p.memberid = TEMP.MemberID
               AND p.EffectiveDate = TEMP.effectivedate
               AND p.memberid NOT IN (SELECT MemberID
                                        FROM InvoiceDetail
                                       WHERE ProgramYear = NAME)
```

Comment: it taking to time..
If i execute this portion
SELECT p.ID,Name
    FROM Policies p
    INNER JOIN ProgramYears py ON p.ProgramYearID = py.id
    INNER JOIN (
        SELECT MemberID
            ,max(EffectiveDate) AS EffectiveDate
        FROM Policies
        GROUP BY MemberID
        ) TEMP ON p.memberid = TEMP.MemberID
        AND p.EffectiveDate = TEMP.effectivedate
It takes milli sec. to execute but after that if i excute whole query it takes 9-10 sec to execute .
So i want to optimy  it.

Comment: How many records do you have in specified tables?

Comment: Post an image of the execution plan. Probably missing some indices.

Comment: 283000 in InvoiceDetail
I want to replace "NOT IN" clause

Comment: i m unable to post that image @magnus

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`NOT EXISTS` is usually a better substitute for `NOT IN`, but your choices largely depend on the data and the structure of your tables and indexes.

Try the query below, but compare its execution plan to that of your current query; what works for one scenario may not work for another.

```
 SELECT p.ID, Name
   FROM Policies p
        INNER JOIN ProgramYears py ON p.ProgramYearID = py.id
        INNER JOIN (SELECT MemberID, max(EffectiveDate) AS EffectiveDate
                      FROM Policies
                     GROUP BY MemberID) TEMP
                ON p.memberid = TEMP.MemberID
                   AND p.EffectiveDate = TEMP.effectivedate
  WHERE NOT EXISTS
            (SELECT MemberID
               FROM InvoiceDetail AS ID
              WHERE ID.ProgramYear = NAME
                AND p.MemberId = ID.MemberId)
```

Comment: Thank You Sir..My Problem is Solved.
NOT EXISTS has reduced the execution time from 9 second to 3-4 second.

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
 SELECT a.ID, a.Name
   FROM (SELECT p.ID, Name,
                ROW_NUMBER()OVER(PARTITION BY p.memberid ORDER BY p.EffectiveDate DESC) AS rnk
           FROM Policies p
                INNER JOIN ProgramYears py ON p.ProgramYearID = py.id
          WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT MemberID
                              FROM InvoiceDetail AS ID
                             WHERE ID.ProgramYear = NAME
                               AND p.MemberId = ID.MemberId)
        ) a
  WHERE a.rnk = 1
```